# Push notification not getting in Android when connecting to wifi

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-wifi

My android app uses GCM push message service. When the device is connected to wifi, push notifications are not received on the phone. However, it works fine when connected to Mobile data. But the same time whats app and other applications getting push messages in wifi. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

GCM uses ports 5228, 5229 & 5230 which are almost always blocked on corporate network.

Check this  [forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-4-kitkat/334480-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-behind-firewall.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback

Comment: Is there any solution to solve this issue? Then how whats app and other applications get push notification?

Comment: whatsapp use different ports, thats why it works fine. the solution is u need to enable 5228, 5229 & 5230 ports of your internet router.

Comment: WhatsApp messenger uses the following ports: 5223, 5228, 4244, 5242, 443, 80 and 5222.

Comment: But when i publish the app , how this will work on the users networks?

Comment: What i know. mobile data plan not block the GCM ports. but some wifi networks may block this, so your apps maybe not working with some network that block GCM ports. My app also using GCM.

Comment: Then what is the solution for it?

Comment: No solution for this. who ever using GCM will face this issue.

Comment: Then how Whats app getting push notifications

Comment: as i said in above comment. WhatsApp messenger uses the following ports: 5223, 5228, 4244, 5242, 443, 80 and 5222. Basically ports 80 is always open by default.

Comment: @Finko, do you know how to use these ports open in our application like whats app?

Comment: the ports cannot be open using our application. you must configure your wifi router ports. There are some other push notification beside GCM. such as  [Pushy](http://eladnava.com/pushy-a-new-alternative-to-google-cloud-messaging/)

Comment: @ Finko ,Then how whats app using thses ports?

Comment: They did not use GCM. they use their own Push Notification. u can check this Push Notification library [Pushlets](http://www.pushlets.com/) , [urbanairship](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html), [Pushy](https://pushy.me/)